# How do You Center a TextView in Layout?

Tags: android, layout, center, textview

I have a complex layout, part of which features a value centered over a label, with + and - buttons on either side of the value.  I want the value to center between the buttons, whether it is "1" or "99".  It looks fine when it's a 2-digit number like "99", but when it's a single digit the number is left-justified.  How do I properly center that value?

Here's the portion of my layout that does this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/runway_label"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dec_runway_button"
        android:src="@drawable/minus_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/runway_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40.0sp"
        android:minWidth="50sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#333333"
        android:shadowDx="2.0"
        android:shadowDy="2.0"
        android:shadowRadius="3.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/inc_runway_button"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 43):

It sounds like you want to center the text within the `TextView`, not the `TextView` in the Layout.

You're already explicitly setting the `minWidth` of the `TextView`, which is good.  Have you tried using `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` for the `TextView`?  NOT `layout_gravity` which is the gravity of the `TextView` within the parent, in this case `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is what finally worked for me:

```
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/runway_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minWidth="110sp" android:textColor="#66CCFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="15sp" android:text="@string/runway_label" />
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/runway_label"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/dec_runway_button" android:src="@drawable/minus_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/runway_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="40.0sp"
                android:minWidth="50sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:shadowColor="#333333" android:shadowDx="2.0"
                android:shadowDy="2.0" android:shadowRadius="3.0" />
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/inc_runway_button" android:src="@drawable/plus_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use below line..which works fine to align your `TextView` in center.

**`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`**

Example..

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Text View"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="28sp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` is not working try:

```
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```