# TextView in the center of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, center, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I center text horizontally and vertical in a TextView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android)

I have a `RelativeLayout` (before it was a `LinerLayout`), that occupies all the screen and I want to put in the center of this `Layout`, a `TextView`. I try to do it with `gravity = "center"` `layout_gravity = "center"` and a few more, but it doesn't work.

Anybody knows how to center the `TextView` in the middle of the screen?

**EDIT**

Ok, I think I explained badly. I think the `TextView` is in the center, but what I want to center is the text in the `TextView`. Can I do this?

Comment: try to see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784003/how-do-you-center-a-textview-in-layout it's was always problem.. i don't know xml.. can't help u. but this i always fixed by code.. and never found easy way to do it as i doing it (cos i don't know xml )

Comment: Center both horizontally and vertically? Edit: Rotemmiz beat me to the punch lol. He posted what you're looking for.

Comment: You should add  android:gravity="center"  as in my answer.

Comment: Use android:gravity="center"

Comment: If you are working under RelativeLayout use 
 android:layout_centerVertical="true" and android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" with your TextView of         android:layout_width="wrap_content", if you use         android:layout_width="match_parent"
, use android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If your font size is big enough, it might look like it's not centered, because of the font padding.
Try using the already mentioned properties combined with `android:includeFontPadding`, something like this:

```
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Give bounty please, your question are still in featured :)

Comment: What does `android:includeFontPadding="false"` do?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia, it means Android will take into account the font "white space" that it has above and below, to calculate its position in the layout.

Comment: works like a charm thank you @mdelolmo

Answer (score 18):

If you want to align contents of RelativeLayout in the center then you need to put android:gravity="center" in the RelativeLayout's properties. Below is a sample XML code for it along with its visual representation.

**XML Code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Text View"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Graphical Layout:**

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Try `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` or `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`
these apply to `RelativeLayout`

Comment: The answer here is what you're looking for and will get the TextView object centered within the layout, but you may also still need to add android:gravity="center" so that the text will be centered within the TextView object.

Comment: It doesn't work. My textSize is too large and I don't know how to center it.

Comment: Try posting the xml layout, I will be able to help you further more...

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the `gravity="center"` of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

```
android:gravity="center"
```

works on RelativeLayouts only. So try

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" <!--relative Layout-->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Mint Payments"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, taken from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android)

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/**yourtextstring**" />
```

Comment: I tried this, and doesn't work, the text don't center.

Comment: What layout do you have? Cos it did the trick with linear layout for me.

Comment: I have `RelativeLayout`, I will try with `LinearLayout` and I will tell you.

Comment: i wonder if the other approach works for every other layout.

Comment: it is wrong because you don't understand the question. I test it and doesn't work. @mdelolm knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should display in center of the screen with center aligned. If you want to text alignment, you may use android:gravity="right" or android:gravity="left"

```
     <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:text="This is some text" />    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Txt is aligned in Center" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

use

```
android:gravity="center"
```

attribute for your TextView in layout_XML File.

Comment: this command is false

Comment: android:gravity will work here.